# Firebase query by key and put results into a list

Tags: android, database, firebase, key

I am creating an app using Firebase. The structure of my database is shown in the picture below.

Is "KITu8SJFwd3HsvxUA6b" the key? I want to perform queries by it because it is unique.  I need to get things like "KITu8SJFwd3HsvxUA6b" from rooms/roomName/users/, and then, in the "users" branch below, query by this for "latitude" and "longitude" of that particular user. Finally, put what I get from the query into an ArrayList.

I have no idea what I should do. I guess it would be something like

```
fireBaseRef = new Firebase("https://infoassassinmanager.firebaseio.com/rooms/"+ myRoom + "/users");
fireBaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             fireBaseRef2....
```

But I don't know how to proceed. 
[image]

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I understand... but I don't have access to this database at the moment. I only got the pic showing the basic structure. Btw I am not asking for detailed coding. I just wondered if someone could tell me how to perform a query by that "KITu8SJFwd3HsvxUA6b" thing (actually I don't know what it is but it is the only thing that is unique)